# XML content extraction with jsoup

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, jsoup

I'm using jsoup to extract information from a xml doc as below:

```
<results>
  <status>OK</status>
  <totalTransactions>1</totalTransactions>
  <language>english</language>
  <taxonomy>
    <element>
      <label>/business and industrial/advertising and marketing/telemarketing</label>
      <score>0.805156</score>
    </element>
    <element>
      <confident>no</confident>
      <label>/automotive and vehicles/certified pre-owned</label>
      <score>0.23886</score>
    </element>
    <element>
      <confident>no</confident>
      <label>/shopping/retail</label>
      <score>0.156721</score>
    </element>
  </taxonomy>
</results>
```

What I want from the xml is the text within label and score tag. Thus:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(job[1], "", Parser.xmlParser());

String status = doc.select("status").text();

if (status.equals("OK")) {
    Elements elements = doc.getElementsByTag("element");

    for (Element e : elements) {
            System.out.println(e.select("label").text() + ","
                        + e.select("score").text());
    }
}
```

The program only reads status tag... No text returned from afterwards...

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
String status = doc.select("status").text();
```

This fails if your document has more than one status element. Better explicit use the first one:

```
String status = doc.select("status").first().text();
//                                   ^^^^^^^
```

Same applies for the other selects. The method `select()` always returns an `Elements` object (= a list of `Element`) - therefore `text()` takes the text of all found elements.

---

Your code is ok, using the shown xml instead of `job[1]` returns this:

```
/business and industrial/advertising and marketing/telemarketing,0.805156
/automotive and vehicles/certified pre-owned,0.23886
/shopping/retail,0.156721
```

Have you checked your Xml you receive for errors?